# Calling Subcomponent using JSX throws error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx, tsx

I am trying to call one subcomponent within the same class but it throws an error If I use it with curly braces it's working fine.

Below code throws an error:

```
public TotalCostSavings = () => {
        return <View />;
    };

    public Savings = () => {
        return (
            <View>
                <this.TotalCostSavings />
            </View>
        );
    };
```

Error: `

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports`

The below code works fine:

```
public TotalCostSavings = () => {
        return <View />;
    };

    public Savings = () => {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.TotalCostSavings()}
            </View>
        );
    };
```

Why the first approach is not working?

Comment: Declaring components within components is an anti-pattern anyway...

Comment: @BrianThompson I am trying to break component into several small functions which returns JSX, and then call them to create one component.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the internals of React, but I would assume that `public TotalCostSavings()` is not seen by React as a component, because it's not defined on its own and exported. When you invoke it as a function (second example) the returned value is indeed a component recognized by React.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is just the naming.  React expects that all components start with an uppercase name. If it sees a lowercase name then it assumes it's a built-in DOM element like a `div`. You have a problem because `this` is lowercase, which obviously you cannot change.

This works just fine because the JSX element now has an uppercase name `Aliased`:

```
public Savings = () => {
  const Aliased = this.TotalCostSavings;
  return (
    <View>
      <Aliased />
    </View>
  );
};
```

It would make more sense to define them as functions and call them that way:

```
renderTotalCostSavings = () => {
  return <View />;
};

renderSavings = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.renderTotalCostSavings()}
    </View>
  );
};
```